# Generating Enums Dynamically

Tags: java, enums, runtime

Let's say I have a file whose format is basic XML, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<enum-set>
    <enum>
        <name>SomeEnum</name>
        <values>
            <value>
                <name>SOMEVALUE</name>
                <displayText>This is some value</displayText>
             </value>
            ... more values ...
        </values>
    </enum>
    ... more enums ...
</enum-set>
```

and I wanted to turn `SomeEnum` into something like this at runtime:

```
public enum SomeEnum implements HasDisplayText {
    SOMEVALUE("This is some value"),
    ... more values ...;

    private String displayText;

    SomeEnum(String displayText) {
        this.displayText = displayText;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayText() {
        return displayText;
    }
}
```

... and then pass the newly created enum `SomeEnum` around my application. How might I achieve something like this? Is it doable?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What you're trying to do doesn't make a whole lot of sense. [Enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) are really only for the benefit of compile time, as they represent a fixed set of constants. At runtime, what would be the meaning of a dynamically generated enum - how would this be different from an plain object? For example:

```
public class Salutation implements HasDisplayText {

   private String displayText;

   private Salutation(String displayText) {
       this.displayText = displayText;
   }

   @Override
   public String getDisplayText() {
       return displayText;
   }

   public static Collection<Salutation> loadSalutations(String xml) {
      //parse, instantiate, and return Salutations
   }
}
```

Your XML could be parsed into newly instantiated `Salutation` objects, which could be stored in some `Collection` or otherwise used by your program.  Notice in my example, I've restricted the creation of `Salutation` by giving it a `private` constructor - in this case the only way to retrieve instances is by calling the factory method which takes your XML. I believe this achieves the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Makes sense. I asked about enums specifically because my hierarchy has too many of them now (not an absurd amount, just more than a few) and I was hoping to eliminate them.

Comment: @Chris - Wait, so is your question about code-generation, or creating them at runtime?

Comment: Really it's about creating them at runtime. I suppose that's different.

Comment: @Chris - So you see why anything loaded from XML at runtime wouldn't make sense to be an enum?  If you have unused enums at compile time, you might just delete them and refactor your project.

Comment: None of them are unused. They all have uses, I'd just like to be able to create them at runtime rather than have them sitting around. I am eventually passing all of these enums to different classes to be used.

Comment: @Chris - As long as something's used, it's okay for it to sit around for a while ;)  The whole point of using enums is to make programming easier for you (and anyone else who works on the project). If anything, I'm always interested in how I can make something known at compile time instead of runtime.

Answer (score 14):

Actually it *is* possible to create enum instances dynamically, but it's a total hack, I wouldn't advise it at all - maybe you're misunderstanding the nature of an `enum`, it's a compile-time feature of the language, and you're not supposed to add/remove instances from it at runtime.

Anyway, if you're interested in the hack for creating enum instances dynamically, take a look at this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190203123924/https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue161.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but please insert some sample lines in this answer and add the link to the article. It helps a lot if the page will ever shut down.

Comment: The article was already linked. To be on the safe side I added a link to the Internet Archive. It's quite a bit of code and explanations, in this case it's better to just go and read the article.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic Enums is the answer to your problem:

```
public abstract class DEnum<E extends DEnum<E>> implements Comparable<E>, Serializable {
```

This class has a signature similar to the standard Enum class. It has a protected constructor to allow instance creation in concrete Enum classes. For example:

```
public class YesNo extends DEnum<YesNo> {

    public final static YesNo YES = new YesNo();
    public final static YesNo NO = new YesNo();
```

The DEnum class knows the names of the members by introspection:

```
String name = YesNo.YES.getName();
YesNo yes = YesNo.get(YesNo.class, name);
assert (yes == YesNo.YES);
```

There is a typed getter that retrieves all the items:

```
YesNo[] items = yes.getItems();
assert (items.length == 2);
```

It allows to add members dynamically at run time with (from database or from file):

```
YesNo maybe = getOrCreateIfNotExists(YesNo.class, "MAYBE");
items = yes.getItems();
assert (items.length == 3);
```

Which have the same behavior as the static members:

```
YesNo unknown = YesNo.get(YesNo.class, "MAYBE");
assert (unknown == maybe);
```

Comment: You should include a link to the implementation of `DEnum`, or post it here

Comment: similar implementation here https://github.com/novarto-oss/lang/tree/master/lang/src/main/java/com/novarto/lang/denum

Comment: public final static YesNo YES = new YesNo(); is not dynamic, it is static

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Oscar Lopez. Here is what i did, a sort of hack.

```
public static enum Setter {

    DYNAMIC_ENUM_EXAMPLE {

        @Override
        public String setGetValue(String yourValue) {
            return "prefix " + yourValue + " postfix";
        }
    };
    public abstract String setGetValue(String value);
}
```

You can get the value like this :

```
Setter.DYNAMIC_ENUM_EXAMPLE.setGetValue("namaste")
```

Output :

```
prefix namaste postfix
```