# Is there any way to create Java Enum from a File?

Tags: java, file, enums, reference

I'm trying to create an Enumeration in Java. I did a code I created a comboBox with the enum values and it was correct. The problem is that in that case I knew the values I wanted ComboBox to have.

Now I'm trying to create a ComboBox in SceneBuilder with an object characteristic.
I receive from a file a lot of tasks and all of them have it own reference. I want to create an enum with all the references with the objective that user chose one task from the reference in the ComboBox.

Here is the Task code in portuguese (referencia means reference):

```
//This is a constructor of Tarefa (task): 
public Tarefa(String referencia, String designacao, String descricaoInformal, String descricaoTecnica, int duracaoEstimada, Double custoEstimado) {
        this.referencia = referencia;
        this.designacao = designacao;
        this.descricaoInformal = descricaoInformal;
        this.descricaoTecnica = descricaoTecnica;
        this.duracaoEstimada = duracaoEstimada;
        this.custoEstimado = custoEstimado;
    }

public String getReferencia() {
        return referencia;
    }
```

I was creating other JavaClass creating something like this:

```
public enum Prioridade {
    BAIXA {
        public String toString() {
            return "Baixa";
        }
    },
    ABAIXO_NORMAL {
        public String toString() {
            return "Abaixo do Normal";
        }
    },
    NORMAL {
        public String toString() {
            return "Normal";
        }
    },
    ACIMA_NORMAL {
        public String toString() {
            return "Acima do Normal";
        }
    },
    ELEVADO {
        public String toString() {
            return "Elevado";
        }
    },
    TEMPO_REAL {
        public String toString() {
            return "Tempo Real";
        }
    };
}
```

But in that case I knew the values I wanted enum to have.

How can I create an Enum not knowing from the beggining the values it will have? I only know the type: String.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating Enums Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467215/generating-enums-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

You can use static method of enum `valueOf(String str)`
For example `Prioridade.valueOf("ACIMA_NORMAL")`

Comment: Yes, but in that solution I know the value of enum. What I'm trying to solve is opening a file and save the  taks's references in an enum

Comment: You have a string value of enum ,not?

Comment: I will receive from a file some tasks. And I need to add one task's characteristic to comboBox. So, the ComboBox will have the task's reference (that is a String value) that will receive from the file.(The tasks are defined by reference, name, days needed, etc)