# How can I access String resource in top function of Kotlin for enum class in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

ELevel is enum class in a top function of Koltin, but the Code A is hard code.

So I try to use Code B, but it's wrong, how can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
enum class ELevel(val label:String){
   Whisper("Whisper"),
   Quiet("Quiet Library") 
}
```

**Code B**

```
enum class ELevel(val label:String){
  Whisper(getApplicationContext().getString(R.String.Whisper)),
   Quiet(getApplicationContext().getString(R.String.Quiet)) 
}
    
<resources>
    <string name="Whisper">Whisper</string>
    <string name="Quiet">Quiet Library</string>    
</resources>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467215/generating-enums-dynamically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
enum class ELevel(private val labelId: Int){
    Whisper(R.string.whisper),
    Quiet(R.string.quiet);

    fun getLabel(context: Context) =
        context.getString(labelId)
}
```

The downside is you have to pass a Context instance each time, but it's the safer way to do it.

An alternate way to do it is like this:

```
enum class ELevel(private val labelId: Int){
    Whisper(R.string.whisper),
    Quiet(R.string.quiet);

    lateinit var label: String
        private set

    companion object {
        fun initialize(context: Context) {
            for (value in EValue.values()) value.label = context.getString(value.labelId)
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your `MainActivity.onCreate()`, call `ELevel.initialize(applicationContext)`. But you have to be careful not to use the `label` property in any code that is run before `onCreate()`, like in a property initializer. If you use the enum in any Services, then you need to call `initialize()` in your Application subclass's `onCreate()` instead, but then you need to watch out for [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211036/why-backup-related-process-might-cause-applications-oncreate-is-not-executed).

Comment: Thanks! But `for (value in values) `  can't be compiled!

Comment: It should be for (value in values()). Sorry